# How to add uniquness check for an association in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I'm currently working on a notes project and I need the notes name to be checked for uniqueness in the scope of the owner on the database level, is it possible? I've already add a validation in my model, but having it both in model and database would be great)

The note belongs_to :user and the user has_many :notes. I need the validation for only note name.

Comment: Do you want to scope it to the `user` or the database owner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to validate the uniqueness in the model along with scoping it to the user, you could use the following in the `Note` model.

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :user }
end
```

But if you want to enforce it in the database as well, you can use the following in your migration:

```
add_index :notes, [:user_id, :name], :unique => true
```

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Altered from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026441/how-do-i-specify-a-column-to-be-unique-in-the-scope-of-a-relationship-in-sql-ser), I think you could do

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.notes WITH CHECK ADD
    CONSTRAINT UQ_notes_name UNIQUE (name, user_id)
```

or

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IXU_notes_name ON dbo.notes(name, user_id)
```

This would make sure the same user could not have two notes with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `UNIQUE` index in your database for two columns: `name` and `user_id` (or whatever they're called in your db).